# Crash in iOS 5 with child NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

Creating new child NSmanagedObjectContext in main thread, creating new entity in it and after all saving this context causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS after some time.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSK7o.png)

Sample of code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
[BPEntity MR_createInContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

What can I do to avoid this?

UPD

Sorry, didn't tell that I use ARC. Deallocated object is context, becouse if I call

```
[context performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"retain")]; //same as [context retain]
```

everything all right.

If I using NSZombieEnabled - everything all right! %(
Breakpoint on exceptions setted.

Comment: Please provide some more code

Comment: Have you got DEBUG set in your PCH or defines. If you have altered your model between runs then the default clearing behavior in MR wont work without it. https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/GettingStarted.md

Comment: It doesn't matter seted DEBUG or not. I'm don't altered model

Comment: Not enough information. Your crash image suggests that you're trying to use an object which has been deallocated, but doesn't provide any information about which object that is. Try using `NSZombieEnabled` and setting a breakpoint on exceptions, that may help you find out which object.